# Is dependency injection container shared between azure functions from one pack?

Tags: azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I've created a few Azure Functions projects. I deploy them all at once in one zip file. I have different initialization of an interface, which I register as a singleton to DI in different Azure Functions.

I'm facing problem that only first (with `.TryAddSingleton` only the last) object is registered. That is a problem as independent Azure Function seems not to be isolated and uses object registered in different Azure Function project.

Is this behavior intended?

Only reason I can think of is some kind optimization of memory usage, nevertheless, I would really appreciate to have possibility to strictly divide DI context per function. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions are running on the same instance(VM), and singleton service is reused across function executions on the same instance. That's why they are not isolated.

The workaround is using different [hosting plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale) for the functions.